# Fast way to check disk usage in linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssh, centos

I want to find out the disk usage of /home however it's too slow, I get timeout sometimes (SSH) because it has lots of files. I am using `du -sh /home` and I was wondering if there's a faster way?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get a faster result.  You can use [screen](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/) to detach your session though and reconnect after the timeout.  Use `screen du -sh /home` to run it, press 'CTRL+A' then 'd' to detach, and run `screen -r` after your timeout to renew the session.

Comment: Why not just run the command in the background as a job?

Comment: Related post: [How to cache or otherwise speed up du summaries?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8485)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have */home* on a separate partition you can use `df -h` to show the disk usage. This should be pretty fast since the command doesn't summarize the disk usage of each file (as `du` does).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df -kh
```

it will show disk usage. and if you want to see for all drives then use

```
sudo fdisk -l
```